# Filtering on SQLAlchemy @hybrid_property not working

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy Model as follows and am trying to filter on the isActive property.

```
query(PersonMedications).filter(PersonMedication.isActive==False).all()
```

---

```
class PersonMedication(ModelAbstract):

    __tablename__ = "personMedication"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    startDate = db.Column(db.Date)
    endDate = db.Column(db.Date)
    isCanceled = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    @hybrid_property
    def isActive(self):
        if self.isCanceled == True:
            return False
        elif self.endDate and self.endDate < datetime.date.today():
            return False
        elif self.startDate and self.startDate <= datetime.date.today():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

From looking at the SQLAlchemy docs it seems like my function should work.. What am I missing?

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

## UPDATES

Per @van's suggestions I figured out I need to use an expression function but cant seem to figure out the correct syntax for stringing together the logic.

```
@isActive.expression
def isActive(cls):
    return not cls.isCanceled and cls.startDate <= func.current_date()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to define an `SQL` expression for this properly, as `sqlalchemy` can only handle very trivial cases where the python expression is one-2-one with the SQL.

Read more on the topic in the same documentation page [Defining Expression Behavior Distinct from Attribute Behavior](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior).

In your case the logic for `isValid == True` looks as following:

- not isCancelled
- startDate is not null, and is before or equal today
- endDate is either null or after today

The code below expresses this in terms of sql clauses:

```
@isActive.expression
def isActive(cls):
    today = datetime.date.today()  # or replace with respective func.???

    return db.and_(
        cls.isCanceled == False,  # @note: assume it is not NULLable
        db.and_(cls.startDate != None, cls.startDate <= today),
        db.or_(cls.endDate == None, cls.endDate > today),
    )
```

In which case you can perform following queries:

```
# active
query(PersonMedications).filter(PersonMedication.isActive).all()
# not active
query(PersonMedications).filter(~PersonMedication.isActive).all()
```

Comment: Thanks Van. I updated the post, cant seem to figure out how to string the boolean logic together into a way that SQLAlchme understands.